# Cannot connect to VM on Google Cloud GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have lost my ssh keys and I am unable to connect to my VM. Even with account authentication I cannot get inside the machine (using gcloud compute ssh vm_name). The cloud shell also doesn't work! I have also tried generating and adding new public ssh keys manually to the VM. Still nothing! How can I access my own VM???

Comment: Use the Google Cloud Console and click the SSH button. If that does not work, then you will need to post details in your question. Start by review the Cloud Logging logs, Serial Port output, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to VM instances through either Cloud Shell(gcloud) or through Google Cloud Console. In the Google Console, you can connect to VM instances by following the steps mentioned in [connect to Linux VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance)

Sometimes you can encounter some error while using SSH to connect to Compute engine VM’s. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) you can find some details about troubleshooting SSH.
To know more about Managing SSH keys, you can check [Managing SSH keys in Metadata.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)